# GPS tracking not working after receiving low memory warning?

Tags: iphone, memory, gps, location, cllocationmanager

Has someone noticed this odd behaviour? I can't reproduce this for 100% but it happens a lot. I'm not even sure if this is related to low memory warnings at all.

How to (sometimes) reproduce: (on an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.3, all Apps have `UIBackgroundModes = location` so Multitasking is fully enabled)

1. Start 1st GPS tracking app (App A). start tracking
2. Start 2nd GPS tracking app (App B). start tracking
3. Start 3rd GPS tracking app (App C). start tracking
4. Walk 100 meters away
5. Stand still
6. Start another GPS app which is a bit more memory and cpu intensive
7. Turn around and walk 100 m back
8. Stop all GPS tracking app and see tracked trace result

**Result:**

App B and C both tracked the full 200 m successfully. But App A (first App I started) only tracked 100 m (to the point 5. where I started the 4th GPS app).

App A did not crash. It was still running when I switched back (there was no low memory crash log or normal crash log, nothing). And it didn't receive location updates anymore until I restarted the app.

Then I did another try with same setup. But this time App A, B and C all tracked 200 meters.

So my only explanation is that App A is not receiving any location updates anymore after a low memory warning (maybe level=2 ?).

Is there an other explanation to this odd behaviour? How can I fix my app (App A) to still receiving location updates after it has been stopped? (a timer to restart location manager doesn't help)

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: @Chris why do you say that?  There is almost certainly a way for the OP to program his way out of this problem, but we just have to figure out what it is. :)

Comment: @Chris: read the question very carefully. This is not about programming, and yet this IS a programming Q&A site. We may indeed be able to help, but this isn't the proper place for these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Chris -- I see what you mean.  I suppose if there was a code section that could be addressed in the answer, it could turn into a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, if you are getting level 2 low memory warnings, the OS is very quick to kill the offending app.  There may be a level in between where the GPS reporting is blocked, but I doubt it.

Is it always the first app (app A in your example) that doesn't track?

Comment: yes it seems so that it is the first app that doesnt track anymore.

Comment: Hmm. I suggest putting in some `NSLog()`s at the point in App A where it collects the data, and troubleshooting from there.  The memory warning level 2 is something you want to track down.